# What happens on the wire once an IP is assigned to an interface?

Tags: linux, kernel

When an interface, e.g. eth0 gets assigned:

```
inet 192.168.1.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
```

what happens on the wire? does the kernel send any special packet announcing its own ip?

or is it mostly just a filtering on the kernel side, meaning it was always receiving all ethernet/wlan frames but now drops those that doesn't match its IP and deliver the rest to next layer of networking stack.

Comment: There is not a single "special packet" that could be named here. The responses to ARP packets (mapping MAC adresses to IP adresses) will contain the new assigned IP.

Comment: This is largely offtopic here, this looks like a question for https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov This is *not* a good question for the networkengineering SE; that's for network *engineering* -- i.e. for people designing and managing enterprise networks, not for basic questions about how IP works.

Comment: @GordonDavisson "How IP works" is not a topic of UNIX/Linux either :-)

Comment: I'm more interested in how Kernel works here.

Answer (score 1):

Modern OSs tend to check for IP address conflict *just before* assigning an IP address, by sending an ARP query for the IP address they are about to start using, and waiting in the hope that no answers will be returned.

If there is an answer, it means assigning that address would cause an IP address conflict.

After assigning the IP address, operating system *may optionally* send a **gratuitous ARP** message, essentially a broadcasted ARP response indicating the assigned IP address and the MAC address of the network interface. It could be a "response" without a corresponding query, or if the host did IP address conflict detection just before, it can effectively answer its own queries in a broadcasted form.

This can be particularly useful in cases where that IP address (and often the MAC address associated with it) was recently active somewhere else on the same network segment, like when a VM or a clustered service fails over from one host or NIC to another. The gratuitous ARP can inform network switches of the new port location of a particular MAC address, minimizing delays and lost packets in failover situations.

If a host is configured with a static IP address and opts not to do any IP conflict detection nor gratuitous ARPs, the actual IP address assignment can happen completely silently as far as the network is concerned. But in a normal network (with no manually configured ARP tables in routers), it must answer to an ARP request as soon as any other host attempts to send something to that IP address, or else it will only be able to receive broadcast packets.

Comment: so, an ARP request is sent for that IP (no MAC specified) and once an answer returns, all packets are sent to that IP:MAC combo. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's how normal ARP request and response work, and that's what happens if the host with the newly-configured IP did not send a gratuitous ARP, or the other systems in the network chose to ignore gratuitous ARPs, or so much time passed between the IP configuration and someone attempting to actually send to that IP that the information expired from the other hosts' and switch(es)'s ARP/MAC tables.